# backbone validate pairs of fields

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I am currently using Backbone.validate to do form validations.

I need to be able to validate pairs of fields, meaning if you start filling in 'field1' then you have to fill in 'field2' as well, and the other way around. If you leave them blank then the validation passes.

I have backbone.validate setup and working for single fields.

is there anything that i can use that is already part of validation to declare this? i cannot seem to be able to find anything related.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is how i solved it using Backbone.validation
https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation

```
  validateFlickr: function (value, attr, computedState) {
    return this.validatePairs(value, attr, computedState, "flickr");
  },
  validatePairs: function (value, attr, computedState, name) {
    var totalNotBlank =
      (computedState["app_id_" + name] != "" ? 1 : 0)
        + (computedState["app_secret_" + name] != "" ? 1 : 0);

    if (totalNotBlank == 1) {
      return "Need to enter " + name + " App ID and App Secret";
    }
  },
```

And the validation hash:

```
validation: {
    app_id_flickr: "validateFlickr",
    app_secret_flickr: "validateFlickr"
}
```

Comment: That is pretty much how we also do it. Also, could you edit question and provide link to validation library, it might help other people checking this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in to manage this. But you can use the validator API to add your custom methods:

JS

```
$.validator.addMethod( "custom-rule", function( value ) {
    return true; // put your logic here
}, function() {
    return "error message";
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" class="custom-rule">
```